# Image not loading in IE7

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7

I have an image which is assigned as background image for h1 tag(Image is of type PNG).This image is not loading in IE7 for the first time when the page is loaded,but it is loading in page refresh.Can someone help me in resolving this issue?

h1 {
    background-image: url(/images/song/live.png);
}

```
<h1 style="margin-left: 15px;">Welcome... Do you know that New song. "I want to Live"?</h1>
```

Comment: sounds like ie 7 has the image cached and is loading the cached version the second time. Empty your cache (temporary internet files) and im willing to bet the image will never load. suggesting a path is wrong or the image is not on the server.

Comment: try removing the first forward slash so url(images/song/live.png); older browsers might have a hard time rendering it correctly.

Comment: tried clearing cache,same result!

Comment: path is correct,and image is present in the server

Comment: have you tried inspecting the http response in web developer tools f12 i think in ie7?

Comment: I inspected the element,seems the css is applied properly

Comment: what is the http response? is it a 404?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Still using IE 7? if you start fixing the IE 7 issues, there is no end to it. You will spend more money on fixing the issues. Look at the link below and you will see the frustration. Windows XP sales was withdrawn in 2008 itself. IE 7 cannot be installed in Windows 7. Spending energy on fixing the IE 7 issues is not worth also.

http://www.v3.co.uk/v3-uk/it-sneak-blog/2184533/australian-retail-firm-web-tax-internet-explorer-customers

As a temporary solution, wrap the  inside a table.